# How to get the index of non-zero value in a numpy array quickly?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, data-structures

Now I am writing a function which is to get the index of the non-zero values with following rules:

1. The expected result is a list. Each element denotes the index of a continue slice of non-zero values. So for a list of `[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]`, it should get the list `[[3,4,5], [7,8]]`
2. The index of different values in the list should be in separated list, that is, for the list of `[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,0]`, the expected result is `[[2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]`.

Do you have any idea? Thank you in advance!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, can you please show us what you've tried already? and what's your problem with your code?

Comment: @Kasramvd I tried thinking hours but can not figure out a good solution except inefficient for loop. I don't think I can't ask for help until I write some code with bugs.

Comment: First off your code is a proof of your words, secondly it will help us to figure out what you want exactly and it can save the time, and more importantly you can identify the blind spots ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `arr` as input array and to have a list of arrays as output, you could do something like this  -

```
# Store non-zero element indices
idx = np.where(arr)[0]

# Get indices where the shifts occur, i.e. positions where groups of identical 
# elements are separated. For this we perform differnetiation and look for 
# non-zero values and then get those positions. Finally, add 1 to compensate 
# for differentiation that would have decreased those shift indices by 1.
shift_idx = np.where(np.diff(arr[idx])!=0)[0]+1

# Split the non-zero indices at those shifts for final output
out = np.split(idx,shift_idx)
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [35]: arr
Out[35]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0])

In [36]: out
Out[36]: 
[array([2, 3, 4]),
 array([5, 6]),
 array([7, 8]),
 array([10, 11]),
 array([12]),
 array([13, 14, 15])]
```